# Visual studio 2015 SDK and Build Tool Issues

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10, windows-build-tools

First of all, whenever I try to make a C++ project VS2015 returns "Could not find a suitable SDK to target." Even though I have build tools V141 and SDK 10.0.14393, I have tried repairing almost every component that I think is having an issue and these errors still occur.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd be better off with a newer version of Visual Studio. Do you have any specific reasons to use Visual Studio 2015?. It's archaic. Try the 2019 or 2022 versions that have better integration with newer versions of Windows SDKs.

If you still want the Visual Studio 2015, try reinstalling it after removing it using the Visual Studio installer. Take some time to manually remove any leftover directories associated with previous installs. When reinstalling try not to pick the latest versions of Windows 10 SDKs and You'll get these options in the individual components section of the installer. (because I don't believe Microsoft still offers support for Visual Studio 2015, so even if there are issues they wouldn't care much about it). If you've installed the Windows 10 SDK as a separate install using its own .msi installer instead as a bundled workload with Visual Studio try uninstalling it and use the Visual Studio installer to reinstall it. Hope this helps!.